# Access local host network from container without exposing any port?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, localhost, host

**CONTEXT**

I can access to some localhosts of other computers in my local network. For instance, one of them is called `pandahost`, so if I browse `pandahost` in my browser, I can access it.

Currently I have been working with docker, and I have the following Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services: 
  myproject: 
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-for-my-project-environment
    shm_size: 2gb
    volumes: 
      - "D:/project/myproject1/folder:/myproject1"
      - "D:/project/myproject2:/myproject2"
```

I use this docker-compose file to run multiple instances of the service `myproject`, so I don't want to expose any port in order to avoid port conflicts.

Up to this point, everything works fine for my **except that I can't connect to `pandahost` from the service containers**.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way of connecting the service `myproject` container to `pandahost` without exposing any port and without breaking the possibility of having multiple instances of `myproject` service containers?

Answer (score 0):

if you know the port that your container is opening you can simply fetch the IP address of the container using the following command:

```
alias docker_ip_address="docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'"

docker_ip_address $container_ID
```

or more simply

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $container_ID
```

In this case I suggest you name your container using the `container_name` block in your docker-compose.yml to simplify the previous operation.